# JavaScript Смена картинок

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, у меня такая проблема. Есть код смены картинок, он работает, но сменяет картинки резко, не плавно, и нельзя сделать гиперссылки на картинки.Но есть удобная функция смены картинок (следующая - предыдущая):

код:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
all_images = new Array (
"1.png",
"2.png",
"3.png",
"4.png");
var ImgNum = 0;
var ImgLength = all_images.length - 1;
var delay = 5000;
var lock = false;
var run;

function chgImg(direction) {
 if (document.images) {
  ImgNum = ImgNum + direction;
  if (ImgNum > ImgLength) { ImgNum = 0; }
  if (ImgNum < 0) { ImgNum = ImgLength; }
  document.slide_show.src = all_images[ImgNum];
 }
}

function auto() {
 if (lock == true) {
  lock = false;
  window.clearInterval(run);
 }
 else if (lock == false) {
  lock = true;
  run = setInterval("chgImg(1)", delay);
 }
}
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 auto();
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="conteiner">
<div align="center">
 <table border="0">

  <tr align="center">
   <td colspan="3"><img src="1.png" name="slide_show"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="right"><a href="javascript:chgImg(-1)">Предыдущая</a></td>
   <td align="left"><a href="javascript:chgImg(1)">Следующая</a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Есть так же другой код, он подходит мне больше, но он не работает почему то, тут плавная смена картинок. Но как я понял тут не работают ссылки, работает только первая ссылка на всех картинках, и нету прокрутки картинок.

код:

```
java: 
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function theRotator() { $('div#rotator div').css({opacity: 0.0}); $('div#rotator div:first').css({opacity: 1.0}); setInterval('rotate()',2000); } function rotate() { var current = ($('div#rotator div.show')? $('div#rotator div.show') : $('div#rotator div:first')); var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div#rotator div:first') :current.next()) : $('div#rotator div:first')); next.css({opacity: 0.0}) .addClass('show') .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000); current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000) .removeClass('show'); }; $(document).ready(function() { theRotator(); });
// ]]></script>

html:
<div id="rotator">
<div class="show"><a href="---"><img src="1.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
<div><a href="---"><img src="2.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<div><a href="---"><img src="3.png" alt="" /></a></div>
<div><a href="---"><img src="4.png" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Хотел бы узнать, можно как нибудь сделать так что бы html код был как во втором варианте, потому что ещё много блоков поверх картинки хочу добавить, что бы смена была плавной, и можно было листать картинки вперёд и назад как в первом коде. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал на быструю руку. Но думаю алгоритм действий понятен. За основу можно взять `div` и при нажатии соответствующих кнопок изменять позицию `left`. Код можно оптимизировать как угодно. В блоках `image-block` вы можете размещать и ссылки и картинки.  Надеюсь сможете адаптировать под свой сайт))

```js
var gallery = {
  cnt: 0,
  container: document.getElementById("container_image"),
  timer: null,
  rds: "btn1",
  pos: 0,
  top: 1,
  init: function(i) {
    this.cnt = i;
    this.container.style.width = i * 700 + "px";
    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
      gallery.start();
    }, 1500);
  },
  start: function() {
    if (this.top == 1) {
      this.pos = 0;
      this.top += 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if (this.top == 2) {
      this.pos -= 350 * 2;
      this.top += 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if (this.top == 3) {
      this.pos -= 350 * 2;
      this.top = 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    this.container.style.left = this.pos + "px";
  },
  slide: function(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    var target = e.target;

    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "span") return;

    var id_click = target.id;
    var pos = document.getElementById(id_click).offsetLeft;
    if (id_click == "btn1") pos = 0;
    else if (id_click == "btn2") pos -= 526 * 2;
    else if (id_click == "btn3") pos -= 593 * 3;
    else pos = 247;
    this.container.style.left = pos + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.prev {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.next {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background: green;
}
.container-photo {
  width: 920px;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
}
.image-block {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.rds {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.rds-bl {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Прокрутка изображений</title>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      gallery.init(3);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
      <div class="container-photo" id="container_image">
        <div class="image-block" id="image_block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="rds" onclick="gallery.slide(event)">
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn1"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn2"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А возможно ли сделать к этому коду автопрокрутку? с этим же стилем. Смена идеальна, красива, очень нравится, просто если можно добавьте пожалуйста автоматическую смену

Comment: А кнопки то нужны или вместо них?

Comment: Да кнопки тоже нужны, что бы пользователь мог пролистать вперёд или назад при желании

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное